# Best Forum plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there any good forum plugin out there for WP  3.3.1 ?

Our site have a single login to post topics and send replys to those topis, so i need a forum plugin that already have user login .please somebody help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally recommend bbPress (plugin).

Its the ForumBB built for Wordpress.

Very Minimal! and works perfect